# How can I speed up this PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

We have a NetApp NAS serving up CIFS shares. On a share that is used by our accounting group someone or some process keeps moving directories which breaks other processes. We turned on auditing in the hopes of catching the culprit. When it happens we guess which logs may cover the time of the event and then pick through the logs to find a clue because there is no event ID for "Hey this folder was moved" so, we try to narrow it down by filtering down ID by ID. I built a PowerShell script that uses -FilterHashTable so we can kick off the script and go off to do something more worthwhile.

```
$evtid = $args[0]
$folder = $args[1]

Get-ChildItem -include *.evt, *.evtx -Path .\log -Recurse |
ForEach-Object {
"Parsing $($_.fullname)`r`n"
$events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{path=$_.fullname;ID=$evtid}
ForEach ($event in $events) {
    $eventXML = [xml]$event.toXML()
    For ($i=0; $i -lt $eventXML.Event.EventData.Data.Count; $i++) {
        Add-Member -InputObject $event -MemberType NoteProperty -Force -Name $eventXML.Event.EventData.Data[$i].name -Value $eventXML.Event.EventData.Data[$i].'#text'
    }
  $events | select * | where ObjectName -Like $folder |Export-CSV ".\Event$($evtid).csv" -Append
  }
}
```

I ran this against an .evtx file with 269,465 events and a filtered out ID that produces 134,837 after and 25 hours I cancelled the script. AM I going to be faced with this? I have exported the .evtx file to a .csv file and tried to search that but it is a 225 MB file and I had to get other tools which are not available to the rest of the company.

Long winded but what I want to know is this: Can you see a way to speed this query up?

Information that is stored for the event

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.netapp.com/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="NetApp-Security-Auditing" Guid="{3CB2A168-FE19-4A4E-BDAD-DCF422F13473}" /> 
  <EventID>4663</EventID> 
  <EventName>Get Object Attributes</EventName> 
  <Version>101.2</Version> 
  <Source>CIFS</Source> 
  <Level>0</Level> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8020000000000000</Keywords> 
  <Result>Audit Success</Result> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-26T14:34:11.343330000Z" /> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Channel>Security</Channel> 
  <Computer>NA1-FAS01/svm_nam-pdfs01</Computer> 
  <ComputerUUID>dd646d34-6fc6-11e8-8c96-00a098bd5477/ae301520-91a2-11e8-a174-00a098bd5477</ComputerUUID> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="SubjectIP" IPVersion="4">10.6.21.11</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectHostname" Source="" /> 
  <Data Name="SubjectUnix" Uid="0" Gid="1" Local="false" /> 
  <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-5-21-1139423721-663753744-1511918330-115546</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectUserIsLocal">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">AMERICAS</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectUserName">AM050240</Data> 
  <Data Name="ObjectServer">Security</Data> 
  <Data Name="ObjectType">Directory</Data> 
  <Data Name="HandleID">00000000000427;00;0000393f;4163de28</Data> 
  <Data Name="ObjectName">(CHIdata);/SOG/NetApp/NetApp Select</Data> 
  <Data Name="InformationRequested">File Type; File Size; Created Time; Last Accessed Time; Last Metadata Modfied Time; Last Modified Time; Allocation size; Delete on last close;</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Comment: 1) Move a folder manually, 2) Observe what events are logged, 3) use `-FilterXPath` to target only events where the corresponding `<Data>` field contains `$folder`

Comment: I followed that process and identified the event and that event ID is one of the most common. The data field is like this:
EventData 
  SubjectIP x.x.x.x 
  SubjectHostname  
  SubjectUnix  
  SubjectUserSid <redacted>
  SubjectUserIsLocal false 
  SubjectDomainName AMERICAS 
  SubjectUserName AM050240 
  ObjectServer Security 
  ObjectType Directory 
  HandleID 
  ObjectName (CHIdata);/SOG/NetApp/NetApp Select 
  InformationRequested File Type; File Size; Created Time; Last Accessed Time; Last Metadata Modfied Time; Last Modified Time; Allocation size; Delete on last close;

Comment: Please put the XML [in your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60869408/edit), comments are terrible for it :)

Comment: Part 2 the actual field I need is ObjectName. However, $eventXML.Event.EventData.Data does not drive all the way down to ObjectName so you have to do a search on that whole field.

Comment: Can I get you to switch to the xml view in EventViewer (or call `ToXml()` on the relevant event instance in powershell) and paste the raw XML, rather than the tabulated output?

Comment: I added the XML